# Elements of below row are being invisible

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am displaying image elements in rows and columns but first element of the below row is always being invisible. I am appending and deleting classes of elements by keyEvents (This is what I imply by saying below row, it means below row of the currentIndex). I want them to be aligned properly. Also, I am not allowed to use flexbox or grid because the app will work in older browsers. HTML code :

```
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
      <Channel v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index" :channel="channel" :ref="index"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  /*flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*min-width:1200px;
  overflow-x:auto;      */
  justify-content: center;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 1 32.7%;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
div > div > div > div {
  padding: 0 4px;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .container::after {
    content: "";
    flex: 0 1 38.7%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Channel component :

```
<div v-if="channel.ChName">
      <img :src="'http://portal.uyanik.tv/resize.php?img='+channelPath+'&type=stb'" :class="{selectedIndex:this.$vnode.key === this.$parent.currentIndex}">
</div>

<style>
div > img{
margin: 10px;
}
.selectedIndex {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: aquamarine;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
</style>
```

Here is how it looks now Also, when you go over the right images, all the images in below row till the same column are being invisible too :

[image]

Edit : If I fix the height of the img to 100px, error is disappearing but I am not allowed to do that as the device is consuming too much memory to handle this task.

Comment: Are you sure that this element is not visible or it is just issue with alignment as you have used float in your code.. This kind of issue can happen if above image is min 1px taller than others.. So please check numbers of elements in your data and displayed on the screen.. Are they match..? And please check sizes of images.. Are they the same..?

Comment: I think it is due to the fact that I am appending a 5px border to one elements.

Comment: Correct.. Border is increasing size of the element and than float attribute will work as on your image..

Comment: @MarioBoss is right. try add    border: 5px solid transparent; to the img style, should work

Comment: @MarioBoss Your solution is not working. I might consider using box-shadow instead.

Comment: One more idea.. If you cannot use flex or grid in your project because you need supporting old browsers, please consider use CSS attributes: 'display:table' for parent element and 'display:table-cell' for child elements